# Why is my JavaScript code not calling my function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am fairly new to JavaScript and made a VERY basic choose your own adventure game with a switch statement. When I attempt to call my function using a button it is unsuccessful. My JavaScript alone is this.

```
function chooseGame(){
var troll = prompt("You are walking through a forest on your way to GameStop. You come   across a troll guarding the only bridge to get there, he says if you pay him he will let you by. Do you PAY, KILL, or CHALLENGE HIM TO A GAME OF CHESS?").toUpperCase();

switch(troll){
case'PAY':
  var money = prompt("Do you have money").toUpperCase();
  var amount = prompt("IS it $50?").toUpperCase();

  if (money && amount === "YES"){
console.log("You pay him and steal the game you wanted, get caught, and go to prison.");   
}else{
console.log("He broke your legs and stole your shoes, not like you'd be needing them.");
}
break;

case'KILL':
  var weapon = prompt("Do you have a weapon?").toUpperCase();
  var friend = prompt("Do you have friends with you?").toUpperCase();

  if (weapon || friend === "YES"){
console.log("You break his legs and take his money buying multiple games.");
}else{
console.log("He brings you back to his personal torture chamber and laughs at your pain for all eternity.");
}
break;

case'CHALLENGE HIM TO A GAME OF CHESS':
  var clever = prompt("Are you clever?").toUpperCase();
  var ability = prompt("Are you good at chess?").toUpperCase();

  if (clever || ability === "YES"){
console.log("You beat him and go on your way to GameStop.");
}else{
console.log("You aren't clever or good at chess, then why did you challenge a troll to a game?");
}
break;
 };
}
```

With my HTML it looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<Script language = "Javacript">
function chooseGame(){
var troll = prompt("You are walking through a forest on your way to GameStop. You come   across a troll guarding the only bridge to get there, he says if you pay him he will let you by. Do you PAY, KILL, or CHALLENGE HIM TO A GAME OF CHESS?").toUpperCase();

switch(troll){
case'PAY':
  var money = prompt("Do you have money").toUpperCase();
  var amount = prompt("IS it $50?").toUpperCase();

  if (money && amount === "YES"){
console.log("You pay him and steal the game you wanted, get caught, and go to prison.");   
}else{
console.log("He broke your legs and stole your shoes, not like you'd be needing them.");
}
break;

case'KILL':
  var weapon = prompt("Do you have a weapon?").toUpperCase();
  var friend = prompt("Do you have friends with you?").toUpperCase();

  if (weapon || friend === "YES"){
console.log("You break his legs and take his money buying multiple games.");
}else{
console.log("He brings you back to his personal torture chamber and laughs at your pain for all eternity.");
}
break;

case'CHALLENGE HIM TO A GAME OF CHESS':
  var clever = prompt("Are you clever?").toUpperCase();
  var ability = prompt("Are you good at chess?").toUpperCase();

  if (clever || ability === "YES"){
console.log("You beat him and go on your way to GameStop.");
}else{
console.log("You aren't clever or good at chess, then why did you challenge a troll to a game?");
}
break;
 };
}
</Script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick = "myFunction();">Game Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my code, as a .html, it displays the button but doesn't do anything when I click it. I was able to make the button alert so I believe this is a problem with my code not calling my function, can someone please alert me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: `myFunction` should be `chooseGame`. What browser are you using? You should find out how to open a JavaScript console (CTRL+SHIFT+I, then click on 'Console' in Chrome) so that you can view the errors in your code.

Comment: Take a look at error console in your browser. It's essential to debug any JS code.

Comment: Either drop the "language" attribute from your `<script>` or spell the language name correctly.

Comment: Good call on the language attribute.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function called myFunction().  You want chooseGame()

```
<button type="button" onclick="chooseGame();">Game Start</button>
```

(also removed the spacing around the equal sign.  that probably isn't breaking it, but is not legal HTML).

Comment: Yes I screwed up while typing and did not notice it, thank you Pointy for pointing that out. The code of myFunction was old I had it at chooseGame and simply posted the wrong version of code.

Answer (score 0):

use `<button type="button" onclick = "chooseGame()">`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (weapon || friend === "YES")
```

you can't write like that.

```
if (weapon === "YES" || friend === "YES")
```